# why did I loose all files with mv command?

Tags: btrfs, mv

I wanted to move one level up the entire content of a directory (with all subfolders)

```
cd /dir/subdir
mv * /dir
cd ..
rm -R subir/
```

In `/dir` I have all folders and subfolders but they are empty. What did I do inappropriately?

Filesystem is BTRFS, I tried `btrfs restore` with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an alias for  `mv`? Run `type -a mv`

Comment: What were the contents of `/dir` and `/dir/subdir` before the `mv` command, and were any of these paths symbolic links? Also, did you have names in `/dir` that also existed under `/dir/subdir` before the `mv` command?  When you say you "tried btrfs restore", what did you do exactly?  Could you also let us know the _actual_ pathnames that were involved, in case these are known to be special.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what you did. I'm assuming all commands are standard tools that have not been tweaked in any way. (Check with `type cd`, `type mv`, and `type rm`. If any say they are `aliased` we need to know this. For example `mv is aliased to 'mv -i'` is something we need to know, but `cd is a shell builtin` or `rm is /bin/rm` is fine.)

1. `cd /dir/subdir`

   Move to absolute path in filesystem. Assuming there were no errors reported you're now in `/dir/subdir`.
2. `mv * /dir`

   Move everything visible in this directory to the absolute directory `/dir`. Assuming there were no files with names starting with `-` (as you forgot the `--`) and no errors were reported, all files and directories that were in `/dir/subdir` are now in `/dir`.

   Files (and subdirectories, if any) were moved, not copied, so file contents will not have been touched or changed in any way *unless* `/dir/subdir` is on a different filesystem to `/dir`.
3. `cd ..`

   Either depending on your shell or providing that `subdir` wasn't a symbolic link to another part of the filesystem, *and* that no errors were reported, you should now be in `/dir`.

   To be absolutely certain what directory you're in, use `pwd -P`.
4. `rm -R subir/`

   This command should probably have failed. But perhaps you meant `rm -R subdir`, in which case the directory `subdir` *and any remaining contents* will have been removed.

   You could have used `rmdir subdir` to remove the directory, allowing the system to warn you if it was unexpectedly not empty.

If the files are empty at this point *and you had no errors with any of the commands you entered*, then they were all empty before you started.